How to find an element relative to the clicked element
I'm trying to use Hyperscript to find the nearest parent element with the class .foo when a user clicks on any element inside a <div>. Here's what I have so far:
<div _="on click log target's closest .foo">
  <details class="foo"><summary>AAA</summary>aaa</details>
  <details class="foo"><summary>BBB</summary>bbb</details>
</div>

My other failed attempts:
_ = "on click log target's closest .foo"
_ = "on click log target's closest <details/>"
_ = "on click log the closest .foo from target"
_ = "on click log the closest .foo to the target"

How can I correctly find and log the nearest .foo parent relative to the clicked element using Hyperscript?
